# converting data from recycler view to string onClick

Tags: android, string, kotlin, android-recyclerview, data-class

**I have a list in a recyclerView, when it clicked, i want it to get a data from the clicked item, and store it in a variable.**

*Here is the code I used.*

> somewhere above the code, `userId` is declared as a String variable

```
adapter!!.listener = { user->
            // do something with your item
            
            Log.d("TAG", user.email)
            userId= user.uid.toString()
        }
```

*Logging to the console works fine, **But it gives the error below***
`java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Void`

Comment: Show your adapter/listener code.

Comment: its there already, it worked for passing args, but now, instead of passing args to another destination, i just want it to store the data i clicked in a var

Comment: the data class has a user pic, firstname, and user id

Comment: i just confirmed, the above code is perfectly correct

Comment: I understand it, but it need to see your adapter.

Comment: it's 54 lines of code

Comment: after `userId=...`, add a new line that just says `null`. Does that fix it?